# htmlunit setTimeOut works in a weird manner

Tags: java, timeout, htmlunit

I have used htmlunit for some time. Now I am trying to introduce a timeout feature to it.
It works in the following way:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
//To disable throwing exception for script errors
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
//To disable java scripts
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
//To disable the loading of CSS
webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
int timeout = 300;
// Add timeout for ETA
webClient.setTimeout(timeout);
try{
    webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
}catch(GeneralSecurityException e){
    log.info("General Security Exception occured");
    log.error("",e);
}
HtmlPage loginPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("myurl");
```

If i reduce the timeout it throws me a `ConnectionTimeOutException`.
But now if i change the order of setting `setTimeout` and `setUseInsecureSSL` it does not work. What i am trying to say is below code does not throw me connection timeout.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
//To disable throwing exception for script errors
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
//To disable java scripts
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
//To disable the loading of CSS
webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
try{
    webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
}catch(GeneralSecurityException e){
    log.info("General Security Exception occured");
    log.error("",e);
} 
//Setting it after setting "setUseInsecureSSL"
int timeout = 300;
// Add timeout for ETA
webClient.setTimeout(timeout);
```

Can anyone explain the cause of this??
Does the order of setting a property matters?

Answer (score 2):

With these questions, people should ALWAYS specify which version of a software, library in this case, they are using or the question can become quite meaningless... Instead of loosing his time on censuring people ("backed by personal experience") the infamous Lizard, Dragon or whatever his name should enforce THAT ("Provide details"). That being said, I confirm that HTMLUnit 2.7 to 2.9 at least with such a code arrangement as shown above as that 2nd non-working example do NOT throw any connection timeout-related exceptions ("answer the question"). Now I will invert the 2 candidate lines in question in our massive program using HTMLUnit and get back to you on this ("share your research"), but nevertheless an explanation from somebody deep inside that library would be appreciated as to why such a phenomenom would happen on Earth! A.R.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised you are trying to use try-catch in this place, since your try-catch will never work.

You are just initializing your `WebClient` and setting features. Remove the try-catch statements and use them when you call `webClient.getPage(...)`.

Also 300 ms is very short if you are targeting some non static pages. Change below according to your needs and do not use try-catch before calling `webClient.getPage(...)`.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(8000);
webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(false);
webClient.getOptions().setGeolocationEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
```